# How to sort TreeView Items using QSortFilterProxyModel based on Combobox Selection

Tags: qt, treeview, qml, qtquick2, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have a TreeView in my app. I limit the displayed rows using a class which is inherited from QSortFilterProxyModel. I also need to sort the items in the TreeView based on selectedIndex of a combobox. 
What I did so far is:

1. When the selected Index of the combo box changes, I will call a function in the class inherited from QSortFilterProxyModel which calls `sort(0)` function.
2. In the class inherited from QSortFilterProxyModel, I have overridden the `lessThan` function and implemented my logic based on the current selection in the ComboBox

The problem is, the sorting does not always happen. When I run the app, and I choose an item in the combobox, the tree items get sorted correctly. But if I select another item in the combobox, the Tree will not get updated. The lessThan function will get called, though!

Comment: You need to provide the code you are using, the information you provided is not sufficient to conclude the problem.

Comment: @Mike I believe the information I provided is enough for the ones who know the answer. As you can see Kevin understood the problem and answered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your proxy is set for dynamic sort/filter, which it likely is, then calling sort() with the same column and sort direction again will do nothing.
See https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/itemmodels/qsortfilterproxymodel.cpp.html#_ZN21QSortFilterProxyModel4sortEiN2Qt9SortOrderE

You will also/alternatively have to call `QSortFilterProxyModel::invalidate()` to trigger resorting.

Comment: thanks, in my case both actions were needed for sorting to work fine. setDynamicSortFilter(false) when creating an instance of QSortFilterProxyModel class, and calling invalidate() before calling sort(0)